# Reload Scripts Assemblies (busy for long time) Unity Freezes

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm Using Unity version 2020.3.32f1 & Rider as Editor. Whenever I make any changes in scripts, even small changes, Unity script assemblies take too much of time to compile and load. Sometimes it freezes Unity entirely and in the Task Manager I can see "application not responding" for the Unity session.

[image: Reload Scripts Assemblies]

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: There are some things to try further down this thread. Especially if you use Rider. https://forum.unity.com/threads/constant-incessant-reload-script-assemblies-program-crashing-hanging.1057568/ But it's a very common issue that seems to get worse with newer versions.

Answer (score 20):

Disable Domain Reloading. To disable Domain Reloading:

1. Go to Edit > Project Settings > Editor
2. Make sure Enter Play Mode Options is enabled.
3. Disable Reload Domain

source https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DomainReloading.html

Answer (score 9):

1. Edit > Project Settings > Editor > Check Enter Play Mode Options
2. Uncheck reload domain & reload scene

That worked for me .. unity 2021.3.4f1

Answer (score 5):

After so much of research, I got one solution which worked for me , in Unity Package manager , Search for Rider & got Update for rider. After Updating Rider version from unity package manager. my Scripts reloading issue got fixed.
[image: Rider update in Unity package manager]

Answer (score 1):

Open **Window->Package Manager**. Select **Packages: In Project** to see the packages currently installed. Remove everything you are not using.

Answer (score 0):

Not being logged in in the Unity editor (upper left corner) certainly seems to increase the chances of this issue happening.

If you open the Package Manager without being logged in you get some errors in the console. I suspect this is related but in the script reload case it just hangs.

Answer (score 0):

#### Restart Unity Editor

Just restarting Unity Editor helped a lot in my case (had Editor open for few days). Reloading assemblies got much faster, from ~40 down to ~15seconds. Now I restart every few hours ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Credits: Found this simple idea [on this site](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1628931/reloading-assemblies-is-extremely-slow-how-to-fix.html).

#### Disconnect Visual Studio

Another thing that *seems* to help is not having connected Visual Studio. Connect it only when you need it for debugging, etc.